# Dropdown using bootstrap asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

[this is how ddl looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV4vC.png)I am trying to use bootstrap classes in asp:dropdownlist but it doesn't change  the look of dropdown as it should. **No bootstrap classes are working**
I also tried using custom css but that too doesnt help, here are three dropdowns i want to use and class from custom css.

```
.selectbox
{
   width: 98%;
   height: 27px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   font: 400 12px/18px 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;
   color: #000;
   font-weight: normal;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   margin: 5px 0 0 0;
   padding: 5px;
}

<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server" Height="40px"  CssClass="selectbox col-md-3"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnit" runat="server" Height="40px" CssClass=" col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMethod" runat="server" Height="40px" CssClass=" col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share how the DropDownlist rendered (as a select) looks like?

Comment: It sounds like maybe your bootstrap tags are not added correctly if none of the bootstrap classes work. Can you share how you added the bootstrap js and css files to the site/page?

Comment: i have checked css and js file more than once. they are properly added, moreover classes does not work only in dropdown everywhere else bootstrap is working perfectly. @Michael_Ulferts